# Don't Know How To Install Softwares In Ubuntu

Tags: software-center

I want To Know How To Download And Install Software. I Know that I can download software from Ubuntu software center, but there are a lot of software that are not available in Ubuntu Software Center. Like Java Jdk8.

Please tell me each and every way by which I can manually install any software. All those terminal commands that are used to install a software... I want to know all of them. As I'm a Windows user and in windows there are `.exe` files and we only have to double click on the exe file for installation.

One More Thing is how to install `.deb` files in Ubuntu
Please Help Me Guys...

Comment: Java.com has very clear and straight instructions about how to install their software. What exactly step are you having issues with?

Comment: Also please just keep a question at a time.

Comment: jdk8 have many problem with Ubuntu, simply use openjdk

Answer (score 0):

First,

1. read and study this [Install additional software](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-install.html)
2. about repositories is here:
   [Add & remove software](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove.html) — [Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-install.html), [remove](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-remove.html), [extra repositories…](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html)
3. [Use Synaptic for more advanced software management](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-install-synaptic.html) — Synaptic is a powerful but complicated software management alternative to Ubuntu Software Center.
4. **Instead any of above**  [Package management with AptGet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) from command line.

Enjoy!